# SQL Framing Query Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a SQL query that only returns a portion of the entire data. In other words, the data is 'framed.' I have an 'ORDER(ORDER BY' part and for whatever reason, that part isn't working all of the time. Sometimes I get what I expect, and other times I don't.

The query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [datetime] DESC, timeMicroSec DESC) AS rowNum,
        ...
    FROM
        ...
    WHERE
        ...
) AS TempTbl
WHERE
    rowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow;
```

The whole data query works when it is not framed and I use an 'ORDER BY' clause at the end. In the image below, the [datetime] column and the [timeMicroSec] column are joined with string concatenation.
[image: View of ordering of results from this query]

As you can see, the ordering is all messed up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't `ORDER BY rowNum` do what you need?

Comment: It does not. I am pulling data together from multiple sources so they will not be ordered in the table by datetime/micros (which is what I need). Also, I believe rowNum will always be 1 to XX no matter what order the underlying data is in.

Comment: @Chris - DOH!  Missed that.  Comment removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you cast a DateTime as a Varchar, it changes the way that SQL Server will order the column.  It will no longer order it chronologically, but instead as just a plain old string.

If the data type is a DateTime, you would get the following descending sort order:

```
01/11/2011
02/22/2010
```

The first date is later chronologically... but if the data type is a Varchar... it would be sorted as:

```
02/22/2010
01/11/2011
```

Because the string "02" comes after "01"... the actual date value doesn't matter at this point.  When you concatenate your date with timeMicroSec, you change the sorting to a Varchar sort.

Like the others said... if you order by RowNum instead of by your concatenated string, you will get a chronological order.

Comment: That was a suspicion of mine; however, I thought the OVER() clause was evaluated first. The conversion to a string is done in the select statement with a function 'dbo.sdrFormatDate([datetime], timeMicroSec)'

Comment: More looking and I see why I get the right result sometimes and not others. It must be the string. Can you explain why rowNum will fix anything? Won't that always be ordered 1 to XX, no matter how the data in the rows in ordered?

Comment: You're right, the OVER clause is evaluated first, but the outer query looks like it is sorting as a varchar to me...  Does the outer query have an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: You built rowNum using ORDER BY [datetime] DESC, timeMicroSec DESC, so rowNum is ordered chronologically, instead of as a varchar.  Ordering by the rowNum will order your results chronologically, even if you're no longer returning a dateTime in your outer select.

Comment: I can see the results of my query working now, just not showing up right in my grid. That is another issue. I appreciate the patients and the help. I now understand exactly what the query is doing!

Answer (score 4):

`ORDER BY rowNum`

as the last part of your query will fix your problem.

Comment: rowNum will always be ordered in TempTbl, that's the nature of the query. What I need is to order the data before rowNum is assigned to rows.

Comment: @Nik - `row_number` does `order` the data by `[datetime] DESC, timeMicroSec DESC` in assigning the numbers so I don't understand why you can't order the result by these?

Comment: Sorry you've lost me completely, rowNum is 1 for the newest date/time and XX for the oldest. Sorting by romNum should give you reverse chronological order. You want to order the results in the subquery?

Comment: @Chris - Martin is right, I just wasn't understanding what the OVER(ORDER BY..) was doing.

Comment: @Nik - good, you should read up on it, makes complicated queries very easy (esp with `PARTITION`).